# How to update folders automatically with IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven configuration that copies my web resources to a directory in target. From there it is read by Jetty. What I want (and what Eclipse always did for me) is update the `target/web` directory when something in the `src/main/webapp` directory changed. I can't get IntelliJ to do the same:

The resource configuration like this:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>less/</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/web</targetPath>
</resource>
```

Right now I have to run the `Generate sources and update folders` everytime I make a change. Can't IntelliJ Detect this automatically?

Notes:

1. I do not build a war but a folder distribution.
2. I already tried moving it to `target/generated-sources/web` but that makes no difference.
3. The target/web is not marked as excluded in the module configuration.
4. The folder is marked as a resource folder. I tried marking it as a source folder but that made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using the [File watchers plug-in](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-watchers.html). This plug-in doesn't ship with IntelliJ by default but it is very useful. From there, you can watch your *.less/html/js files and re-generate them if you edit them. In my case I run the appropriate Maven goals but you can also call the less compiler directly if you want to.

In the configuration set *"Output paths to refresh"* to the the custom directory you are using  (in my case `$OutputPath$/web`). After that, any change should be refreshed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think, yes: try pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd>, type "Import Maven", click the checkbox "Import Maven project automatically". This will enable auto-import which copies resources as well.

Comment: It's already a Maven project. Pressing re-import does not work either.

Comment: Ah, I see - you need instant updates. I'm not sure this is possible, 0:1 for Eclipse :)